# How to batch insert in specific order?

Tags: java, jpa, batch-file

EntityManager doesn't seem to care in which order to persist entities but I need that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be expected for the EntityManager of the JPA implementation to have sufficient intelligence to work out in what order they are inserted in the datastore. At least that's how we develop DataNucleus. The only thing the spec provides for you is that you are responsible for the calls to em.persist() and can do em.flush() where you want to force all to go to the datastore.

--Andy ([DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org))